# Insert row into table if column value does not already exist in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
INSERT INTO LICENSE_TABLE
(code, license_type, distributor)
values ("uniquecode", "standard", "walmart")
```

I want to insert the row only if no row exists that already has `code="uniquecode"`

How can I do this?

I found some solutions involving `INSERT IGNORE`, something about `DUAL`, and a few more, but I did not understand which applies to my situation.

If it matters, I am using `pymysql`.

Comment: You can ALTER your table so the `code` column has a UNIQUE index. That way you get an error in case of entry duplication.

Comment: @dashboard I used your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this uses `on duplicate key update`:

First, you need a unique index, so the *database* maintains the data integrity.

Second:

```
INSERT INTO LICENSE_TABLE (code, license_type, distributor)
    VALUES ('uniquecode', 'standard', 'walmart')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE code = VALUES(code);
```

This is better than a `WHERE` subquery with `EXISTS` because it is *thread-safe*.  That means that multiple updates in different threads will not ever cause a problem.

This is better than `INSERT IGNORE` because `INSERT IGNORE` will ignore other errors.  `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You should first create a `UNIQUE INDEX` on the code column. You can then safely insert the data without warnings using:

```
INSERT INTO LICENSE_TABLE(code, license_type, distributor)
SELECT 'uniquecode', 'standard', 'walmart'
FROM (SELECT 1) AS x
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM LICENSE_TABLE
    WHERE code = 'uniquecode'
)
```

Comment: @user1283776 . . . This is not thread-safe.  Two threads could attempt inserts of the same value at the same time, resulting in an error.  A better answer is `INSERT IGNORE`.  The best answer is `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff why would it be non-thread safe? It is one query. Why would a sane database server interleave the execution?

Comment: . . A second insert could be attempted at exactly the same time.  They would both attempt the update, not see the data in the table (potentially) and one would generate an error due to the unique index.

Comment: @gordon this should not happen in a sane rbms. The second update should wait until first update is finished, at which time it should see the inserted row.

Comment: . . That depends on the locking mechanism.  In general, full serialization is not the default for such operations, because that is quite expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `INSERT IGNORE` like

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO LICENSE_TABLE
(code, license_type, distributor)
values ("uniquecode", "standard", "walmart")
```

But you need to have a unique index on the `code` column. Check if you have one already either with `show indexes from LICENSE_TABLE;` or `show create table LICENSE_TABLE;`

If you don't have one, you can create one like this:

```
create unique index uidx_license_table_code on LICENSE_TABLE(code);
```